# getting lazy data without attaching package

Tags: r, cran

Background:

I have a CRAN R package which has a dependency on lazy-loaded data in another CRAN package of a specific version. I need to avoid using `::` to refer to the data, because it causes CRAN check to fail.

I've read:
[Evaluate function within package environment without attaching package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49852970/evaluate-function-within-package-environment-without-attaching-package)
and
[See if a variable/function exists in a package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214411/see-if-a-variable-function-exists-in-a-package)

I've tried (using nycflights13 for this example):

```
# this works, but I can't use ::
nycflights13::airlines

find("airlines")
# character(0)
get("airlines", envir = asNamespace("nycflights13"), mode = "list")
#Error in get("airlines", envir = asNamespace("nycflights13"), mode = "list") : object 'airlines' of mode 'list' was not found

# attach
library(nycflights13)

get("airlines", envir = asNamespace("nycflights13"), mode = "list")
# works
find("airlines")
# [1] "package:nycflights13"
```

This may make it even more complicated, but I actually want to refer to an active binding, which returns data which may or may not be available.

What I would like:

A CRAN compatible way of referring to lazy-loaded data in another package without using `::` or Imports in DESCRIPTION.

Comment: I think I understand ... and I generally discourage use of foreign packages without `::`, sometimes for a similar reason (CRAN). Doesn't CRAN complain about functions that it cannot find in the base functions or imported packges? Or is that precisely what you are trying to work around, CRAN's enforcing the formal use of `import`, `importFrom`, and `Imports:`?

Comment: I also prefer ::, but the problem is that CRAN will not find this particular object in their older version of the foreign package. I have already loaded the namespace of the foreign package, but as I can't control CRAN's version of the package, R CMD check will fail because it finds ::object which doesn't exist. It of course doesn't matter if I check the version of the dependent package or not, because R CMD check is simply hunting for invalid references anywhere in the code. I already have the version specified in DESCRIPTION as Suggests package >= 1.1 .

Comment: You run into another problem then: if a user installs *this* package from CRAN, then there is a usually-safe assumption that all dependencies are also on CRAN. Perhaps it would be best to keep this dependency-conundrum as a *"you must install this from github/gitlab"*, where it can reference other dev versions of packages and deviate from the CRAN assumption.

Comment: I realize that doesn't address your question, though. I don't have a resolution for that, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I think I'm worsening the problem by trying to follow http://www.tinyverse.org/ and keep an (optional) dependency in Suggests. All this would be solved by making the package in question an Import.

Comment: If the dependent package does have not (yet) exported the functions you are using (either undefined or just not ready), then how will adding the package to `Imports:` help? I would expect the CRAN check to fail. (I hadn't seen tinyverse previously, but it makes a lot of sense.)

Comment: Good point: doing Import version >= x would cement the need to engage with CRAN to have the packages uploaded simultaneously, whereas I hoped to decouple the packages to ease package submission, and possibly be on the automated track instead of taking CRAN maintainer time for manual review.

Answer (score -1):

My workaround was to export a getter function for the external package, for which I am also the author. This works because functions are visible, but lazy data and active bindings (which are set, in my case, in `.onLoad()`) are not.

Another possibility is to use the fact that `::` is a command, so something like this is valid R, and with variable naming on the RHS, it would enable flexibility to query presence or absence of data in namespaces (not just environments on the `search()` path)

```
`::`(nycflights13, airlines)
```

`::` just substitutes the given symbols for strings, and calls `getExportedValue` in `base`.

So, better still, and I think this is my final answer:

```
base::getExportedValue(asNamespace("nycflights13"), "airlines")
```

This works without any `requireNamespace()` or `library()`.